# Why does asp.net core deserialize json null property (list) as an empty list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

ASP.NET Core 5 deserializes json null property (list) as empty list in controller parameter (`HttpPost`).

I did not configure anything in startup.

The property is expected to be null instead of empty list.

Comment: Yes, I did research.

Comment: Please show evidence of your research in the form of links, excerpts, etc. and explain why they didn't help you understand your problem.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/682

Comment: `ASP.NET Core 5 deserializes json null property (list) as empty list in controller parameter (HttpPost).`Can you share your controller and how do you pass json null property (list) to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, it turned out that the parameters in the controllers can be deserialized if the ajax request has an object in data without dataType, contentType. Sometimes it still doesn't work unfortunately, so in those cases I use JSON.stringify, along with contentType="application/json" and the [FromBody] attribute.

As serializer I use Newtonsoft.Json.